# Shortcut for inserting \item in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

Is there a shortcut for printing `\item`, while creating a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>i</kbd>

I posted the question and answered it myself since I couldn't find the answer in shortcut cheat-sheets or directly in any of the forum questions. 

**Edit**

Refer to the Tex Studio Cheat sheet

Comment: It's in the third column, third row under "LaTeX"..